# Mocking external service returns null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I got pretty simple `Dictionary` class that makes a call to external API.

```
 public class Dictionary {
        protected ExternalService service = new ExternalService();       

        public String getValue(String key, String dictionaryName) {
            ExternalServiceInput input = new ExternalServiceInput();
            ExternalServiceOutput output = new ExternalServiceOutput();

            input.setKey(key);
            input.setDictionaryName(dictionaryName);

            try {
                output = service.invoke(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {         
                return null;
            }       

            return output.getValue();       
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but I wanted to write Unit Tests for this, so I decided I need to mock `service.invoke()`.

```
    @Mock   
    private ExternalService service;        

    @InjectMocks
    private Dictionary dictionary;      
    @InjectMocks
    private ExternalServiceOutput output;
    @InjectMocks
    private ExternalServiceInput input;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {      
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        input.setKey("testKey");
        input.setDictionaryName("testDictionary");  
        output.setValue("testValue");           
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnValue() throws Exception {
        when(service.invoke(input)).thenReturn(output);     
        assertEquals(output.getValue(), dictionary.getValue(input.getKey(), input.getDictionaryName()));        
    }
```

I'v tried with `Input` and `Output` as regular field or initialize it in `setUp` method, everything ends up with `NullPointerException` at `Dictionary` class at

```
return output.getValue();
```

Can someone point me what I did wrong?

Comment: Inside a class providing *business behavior* you should not create other objects contributing additional business behavior by invoking the `new` operator. You should **inject** them preferably as *constructor parameters*. Also you should never return a literal `null` to indicate error conditions. Either throw a meaningful exception or return a non null default value (maybe the empty string (`""`) in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override equals and hashCode in your ExternalServiceInput class or change your mock to accept any object of ExternalServiceInput

```
when(service.invoke(Mockito.any(ExternalServiceInput.class))).thenReturn(output);
```